# Android management API for chrome devices

Tags: android, android-management-api, androidappsonchromeos

Actually I am working on my custom MDM for my working. I used android management api for enrolling the devices. I have successfully provisioned and applied policies on android mobile device. Now I have few question regarding android management

1. Does Android Management API also enrolls chrome devices?
2. If Android Management API does not support chrome OS enrollment then all other MDMs which entertain chrome devices too. How does they enroll Chrome Devices?
3. When we apply policies in android management API. We need write the policey in request body. Now what if we want to write our own custom policy which is not in the list of android management api policy request body like changing the wallpaper of device etc.

I just need answers or some hints related to these questions. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. No, Android Management API can only be used to manage Android devices.
2. To manage chrome devices, you can use this [API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-chrome-devices), which is specifically made for that.
3. It is not possible to create a custom policy that is not present in the [policy set](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies). However, you can always send feedback to the API to suggest missing features as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/feedback).